# error populating a table using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am getting the following error when trying to populate a table in view.jsp using jstl to access a List of objects stored in the request object of ViewServlet:

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/view.jsp (line: 34, column: 16) Attribute value invalid for tag forEach according to TLD
```

Can anyone show me how to fix my code so that I populate the table correctly without error?

here are the relevant parts of view.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

        <table>
        <!-- here should go some titles... -->
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>id</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach begin="1" end= "${ no }" step="1" varStatus="loopCounter"
    value="${coursesummaries}" var="coursesummary">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${coursesummary.coursetype}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${coursesummary.numunits}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${coursesummary.id}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

Here are the relevant parts of ViewServlet.java:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
   String idString = req.getParameter("id");
   Long id = new Long(idString);
   List<CourseSummary> coursesummaries = new CourseSummaryDAO().findAll(id);
   req.setAttribute("coursesummaries", coursesummaries);
   jsp.forward(req, resp);
}
```

And here is the entire stack trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/admin/view.jsp (line: 34, column: 16) Attribute value invalid for tag forEach according to TLD
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:237)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1265)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:875)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1798)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    myapp.ViewServlet.doGet(ViewSchoolServlet.java:39)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    myapp.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:56)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `value` attribute, which is not a valid attribute for `<c:forEach>` tag. Perhaps you meant to use `items`:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end= "${ no }" step="1" varStatus="loopCounter"
           items="${coursesummaries}" var="coursesummary">
```

See [`<c:forEach>` Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) for list of valid attributes.

Apart from that, I don't really understand your intent of using `begin`, `end`, and `step`, attribute, given that you are iterating over a Collection. You aren't even using them. And you don't really need them IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for helping.  I am removed begin, end, and step, and so an attempt to load the page not generates an error message: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'coursetype'.  I think this is due to a failure in the database connection, which I am researching separately.  But how can I change the jstl code in the jsp above to more gracefully handle a null value in an expected object?

Comment: @CodeMed. Can you show your Bean? The error is because, the bean doesn't have that property, you are trying to access.

Comment: Thank you for following up.  I do not know what you mean by bean.  Perhaps that is the problem.  I am creating a list of objects in the doGet method, and then trying to iterate through the list of objects with the jstl in the jsp. Can you show some example code?

Comment: Bean - CourseSummary class. Make sure all properties have getters & setters. Also, JSTL itself takes care of null values as blank.